# IllegalStateException thrown when calling ViewFlipper.addView for a second relative layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I want to show more than two relative layouts in a viewFlipper, but running the following code throws an exception

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a
>   parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

Code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < imageid.length; i++)  
{
    RelativeLayout image = new RelativeLayout(MainActivity.this);  

    // image.addView(rrl3);
    // image.addView(rrl4);

    image.setBackgroundResource(imageid[i]);  

    vflp.addView(rrl3);
    vflp.addView(image, new LayoutParams(  
        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
}
```

Comment: May I know why you have added vlfp.addView(rrl3)?. What is rrl3? Can you just remove this and try?

Comment: please post your error stack

Comment: Thanks, i compelted my task, my setting another relative layout and param to it....:)